# Redux Toolkit Query React, dont immediately call queryhook with parameters

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am already using Redux toolkit for a while, but Im just new to the RTK query. Really enjoy it. But when I want to use the query hook, i sometimes dont want to immediately call the hook with parameters, but want to wait to call the hook after a user has entered a parameters (in the example below the variable 'bulbasaur' is just not yet known for me.

How can I do this using RTK query?
In the examples on internet and on their own [website](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query/) I cannot find a example? So, I dont want to call the `useGetPokemonByNameQuery` immediately with the variable `'bulbasaur'`. But I want that the user first to enters a name and then call the `useGetPokemonByNameQuery` with that variable.

It seems such a straightforward question... but I cannot figure out how to do this.

*Code below is an example from their [website](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query/).*

```
Import * as React from 'react'
import { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } from './services/pokemon'

export default function App() {
  // Using a query hook automatically fetches data and returns query values

  // SO: I dont want to call the useGetPokemonByNameQuery immediately with the variable 'bulbasaur', but after the user enters a name.
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery('bulbasaur')
  // Individual hooks are also accessible under the generated endpoints:
  // const { data, error, isLoading } = pokemonApi.endpoints.getPokemonByName.useQuery('bulbasaur')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {error ? (
        <>Oh no, there was an error</>
      ) : isLoading ? (
        <>Loading...</>
      ) : data ? (
        <>
          <h3>{data.species.name}</h3>
          <img src={data.sprites.front_shiny} alt={data.species.name} />
        </>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You could use `useGetPokemonByNameQuery('bulbasaur', { skip: true })` to avoid the fetch based on a condition. But IMO you should just separate the input and create two different components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who are still interested: use the `useLazyQuery` hook ([link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery)).

This can be called any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you miss `reducerPath` for createApi methods then your request generated by Redux Toolkit Query not working

```js
export const brandApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'brandApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: `${BASE_URL}/user/brand` }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getBrand: builder.query<any, void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: '',
        method: 'GET',
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```